# Transparently reconnect to servers after a system suspend

Tags: gnus

I have multiple IMAP and NNTP servers configured in Gnus, mostly over
SSL using the integrated GnuTLS. When I put my laptop into
suspend-to-RAM for a while, the TCP connections will obviously drop
eventually, but Gnus doesn't recognize this, so pressing 'g' after
the system wake-up will cause Gnus to hang while waiting for the TCP
connections to respond. I usually resolve that by restarting Gnus
with `C-g` and `R`.

Is there a way for Gnus to quickly detect dropped TCP connections
and transparently reconnect when I try to update the group list?